# Which cleric powers are usable without a Holy Symbol?

Tags: dnd-4e, cleric

Yesterday I had the privilege of losing my Holy Symbol to a story point. (We all lost everything but our clothes.)  How can I determine what powers, if any, I can use without my Holy Symbol?

Comment: This just happened to us. I wish I'd found this before spending two encounters just flailing about with a stick because I thought I couldn't use healing word.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use (almost) all of your powers when disarmed and without implements.

[Implement](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/glossary.aspx?id=69)<sup>DDI</sup> and [Weapon](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/glossary.aspx?id=89)<sup>DDI</sup> powers don't prevent you from using them if you lack the appropriate tool: they simply allow you to get a bonus when you have the appropriate tool.

---

When using an **Implement** (keyword) power you make an unmodified ability check (usually Wisdom-based for Implement Cleric powers) against the target defense (as per definition of attack roll).

When you hold a magical implement (e.g.: a holy symbol), you get to add the implement's enhancement bonus to both attack rolls and damage rolls with Implement powers (and a damage boost in case of critical hit).

Also note that you can take advantage from any implement you are proficient with (not only holy symbols). If your Cleric took the [Arcane Initiate](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/feat.aspx?id=277)<sup>DDI</sup> feat, then he can use even magical staves, wands and orbs to improve his Cleric powers.

A non-magical implement does not provide any bonus (except for flavor or feat support) unless it is a superior implement. Superior implements cost more but provides a varied array of advantages (properties similar to those of weapons).
For example, the [Astral Symbol](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/item.aspx?id=3469)<sup>DDI</sup> costs 18 gp but has the *Distant* (+2 range of ranged and area powers) and *Energized (radiant)* (+2/+3/+4 damage bonus with Radiant powers) properties. Its base version is non-magical, but it you can buy or create an enchanted version of it.
You gain proficiency with a single type of superior implement by taking the [Superior Implement Training](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/feat.aspx?id=2624)<sup>DDI</sup> feat.

Lack of proficiency with an implement you are using means that you gain no advantage from its superior or magical bonus and properties.

---

When using a **Weapon** (keyword) power while unarmed, you make an unmodified ability check (usually Strength-based for Weapon Cleric powers) against the target defense (usually AC).
However, unarmed attacks have no proficiency bonus, so you lack a thick +2 or +3 modifier.

When you wield a non-improvised weapon you get a proficiency bonus to attack rolls with Weapon powers.

When you wield a magical weapon, you also get the weapon's enchantment bonus to attack rolls and damage rolls with Weapon powers (and a damage boost in case of critical hit).

Lack of proficiency with a weapon you are wielding means that you don't apply the weapon's proficiency bonus and gain no advantage from its magical bonus and properties.

---

Some powers may require you to wield specific weapons or implements. In this case, they **explicitly state** this requirement in their **Requirement** line of the power block. This is usually found in Rogue powers, for example.

Comment: For the sake of anyone else who was confused by the ambiguous wording of the Red Box booklet (or just wants a RAW ref), p62 of the PHB says "Without a holy symbol, a cleric can still use these powers, but he or she doesn’t gain the bonus provided by the magic implement."